# Check if N(large) bits are set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitarray

I want to check if any of the 1024 bits (128 bytes) are set. If all are clear, then I want to do something. Is it possible to do this quickly, i.e one instruction or do I have to loop through my bitmap?

Comment: you have to loop through. You could use SIMD, but i doubt it will gain you anything.

Comment: The good news is that you don't have to check every bit individually. The bad news is that you must loop over your bitmap to check if the values are zero or not. Some other good new: As soon as you detect a non-zero value you can stop looping.

Comment: You ask about speed. Please show the solution you already have as a [mre] in order to provide a foundation (of e.g. data format and consequence of the check) for answers.

Comment: More good news: It's probably possible to use SIMD instructions to check multiple values at once, making it more effective. Also this is highly parallelizable, but setting up and tearing down the threads for this little data will probably be much more work than running in a single thread.

Comment: optimization would be really dependent on the architectures, otherwise with plain C there is little other way than looping and bit operation.
Also I would guess that it would not be the most important part to optimize in your program

Comment: The C standard provides few or no specifications about performance. Therefore, any method “to do this quickly” depends on the implementation. But you have provided no information on the C implementation. Not a compiler name, let alone a version number, not a target processor architecture or model, nothing. No information about whether you have portability needs or are willing to use compiler extensions. You also have provided no information on the context in which this occurs, which can greatly affect performance. There is no information here that can be used to answer your question.

Comment: I meant, more as a general practice. If I want to check a large number of bits for this, is the best way to loop through the bitmap, it looks like it is based on the replies I have received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have understood the questions, you want to check if any of the bit is set out of 1024 bits you have.

Assuming you are on 64 bit machine.
store the bits as array of `unit64_t` type which is `8 bytes`.

So you have array of this kind.

```
uint64_t bits[16] = {0}; // 1024 bits
```

and to check your bit condition

```
for(int i = 0, j=0; i < 16; i++){
    if(bits[i]) {
        return FAIL_CONDITION;
    }
}
return SUCCESS_CONDITION;
```

Comment: This works (if you do the correct number of iterations), but you could do better. Remove the early exit; then the compiler might unroll and optimize the loop. Also, the part about `0xffffffffffffffff` is absolutely pointless.

Comment: How do you figure 12 `uint64_t` elements cover 1024 bits?

Answer (score -1):

Check whether any data is non zero.
Let buffer be the data you want to check,

```
int n=128;
unsigned char *buffer = &data;
for(int i=0 ;i<n ; i++) {
           if((*data)) {  //If data is non zero any of the bit in the data is 
                          // set, so quit from iterating.
                break;
           } 
           data++;
}
```